# How to make a transparent feather pref by css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to add a feather to some images. This is the result I want to end up with:

[image: This picture]

I realize that this question has been posted before, and I have already looked at the options using for example the `box-shadow attr`. I though have a problem with this method. I'm going to have this picture on top of a `webm`, so the background isn't always going to stay the same. That's why I have to make the feather transparent, which I have had no luck with yet! Is this even doable in CSS? This is the result I get when I use box-shadow up until now:

```css
body{
  background:green; 
}
div {
  background: red; 
  width: 200px;
  height: 142px;
  position: relative;
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 18px 20px #fff;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 18px 20px #fff;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
  <div></div>
</body>
</html>
```

I know that a lot of you will just comment that I can set the color of the shadow equal to green, but as defined earlier I want to make it transparent because the background will constantly change.

Thanks in advance for any comments!

Comment: As long as the constraint is "with CSS" I don't think it can be done.

Comment: It can quite easily be done with some HTML and CSS clipping masks. https://css-tricks.com/clipping-masking-css/

Comment: No constraint, changed title now

Answer (score 3):

You could do it with javascript, here's a simple jQuery plugin I just made that works with background images and certain markup.

It's not a completed and tested plugin in any way, I just made it in a few minutes to show the concept, with a few lines of code

```
$.fn.blurry = function(amount) {
    amount = amount || 10;
    return this.each(function() {
        var els = [];

        for (var i = amount; i--;) {
            var el = $('<' + this.tagName + '/>'),
                a  = amount - i;

            el.css('cssText', this.style.cssText);
            el.css({
                position : 'absolute',
                top      : $(this).position().top  + a,
                left     : $(this).position().left + a,
                height   : $(this).height() - (a*2),
                width    : $(this).width() - (a*2),
                opacity  : 1/i,
                backgroundPosition : '-' + a + 'px -' + a +'px'
            });
            els.push(el);
        }

        $(this).parent().append(els).end().remove();
    });
}
```

And here's a [**demonstration**](https://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/9f535hrm/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

HTML:

```
<figure>
  <figcaption></figcaption>
  <img src="your-image.jpg" alt="">
</figure>
```

Css:

```
figure{
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
figure figcaption{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 18px 20px #fff;
}
```

I hope it helps you...

Comment: How is this different from what Rein has in the question? It seems like the same, just with different tags

Answer (score 0):

What I've found to work is SVG filters. It really changes the opacity of the image at the edges, so it can work on backgrounds that change color and backgrounds that are non-solid. It also uses the image's opacity, so it can work on non-rectangular images.

It works on the latest versions of Chrome, Firefox, and Edge, but I haven't tested it on IE, Safari, or Opera, so feel free to comment if it does/doesn't work on those. The [compatibility table](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter#browser_compatibility) for `filter` indicates it should work on all latest versions as long as the `-ms-` prefix is included for IE.

```css
body{
    background: url('https://lorempixel.com/800/800/abstract');
    background-size: cover;
}
img {
    -ms-filter: url(#feather);
    filter: url(#feather);
}
```

```html
<svg height="0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <filter id="feather">
        <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="10"  result="blur"/>
        <feComponentTransfer result="alpha-adjust">
            <feFuncA type="gamma" amplitude="1.1" exponent="8" offset="-0.1"/>
        </feComponentTransfer>
        <feComposite operator="in" in="SourceGraphic" in2="alpha-adjust"/>
    </filter>
</svg>
<img src="https://lorempixel.com/300/200"/>
```

Explanation of the filter:

- The first part is a blur where `stdDeviation` affects the amount of blur and thus, the strength of the feathering (closer to 0 means less feathering).
- The second part adjusts the alpha using an exponential function. Without it, the feather cuts off too soon leaving a sharp edge rather than fading to completely transparent. To adjust for this, `offset` should be negative, `amplitude + offset` should be 1 so the picture remains fully opaque everywhere away from the feather, and `exponent` should be greater than 1 (I've found larger exponents work better).
- The third part applies the alpha from this blurred image to the original image. MDN has great documentation on how to use `feComposite` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/feComposite), but all you really need to know is that the `in` operator is the applicable operator here.

It's important to note that this SVG filter must be present in **all** HTML files that use the effect and the element that uses this effect must contain `filter: url(#feather)` (or whatever you decide to name the filter) in the style.